# How to run pyramid auto arima on Anaconda Jupyter notebook?

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, arima, pyramid-arima

Apparently, Anaconda has a different pyramid package and it is for web framework. https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pyramid

The user guide for arima pyramid suggests that one uses pip to install pyramid-arima. https://www.alkaline-ml.com/pyramid/setup.html#setup

But since Anaconda uses conda to configure packages, how do I add pyramid-arima to the Anaconda environment for Jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 12):

`pyramid-arima` was [recently renamed](https://github.com/tgsmith61591/pmdarima/issues/34) to `pmdarima` to avoid collisions with the Pyramid web framework. Try following the steps in [this link](https://www.alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/setup.html#setup)

Answer (score 1):

To install the package in anaconda for jupyter notebook, the command is:

```
conda install -c saravji pmdarima
```

Comment: While this will work, it should be noted that the package uploaded to conda by saravji is [not officially supported by the pmdarima authors](https://github.com/alkaline-ml/pmdarima/issues/375) and is significantly out of date. The only supported way to install pmdarima (even in conda) is `pip install pmdarima`