# How to install pyramid-arima in python 3.7

Tags: python, forecast

I'm trying to implement auto arima in my python 3.7 on Windows10 So I tried to install pyramid-armia using following command

```
pip install pyramid-arima
```

But I'm getting error message

```
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyramid-arima (from versions: )]
 No matching distribution found for pyramid-arima
```

I also tried steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52910628/how-to-run-pyramid-auto-arima-on-anaconda-jupyter-notebook)

But got the same error message
Can you please guide me to install it?

Comment: Can you share info about what operating system (Windows or Linux or MacOS) and CPU (Intel, AMD, etc.) you have?

Comment: It's Windows 10

Comment: I've [answered your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64030273/941531), you need to use new replacement `pip install pmdarima`.

Comment: Windows 10 of what bits? 32-bit or 64-bit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error might be because there is no version of package that fits combination of versions of your Python, Operating System, Cpu Type and Instruction Set.

That package is out-dated and abandoned, hence not installable, use new replacement, which is [pmdarima](https://pypi.org/project/pmdarima/) package:

```
pip install pmdarima
```

and import like:

```
import pmdarima
```

Official documentation for [pmdarima is here](http://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/).

If still you're getting same error for new `pmdarima` then download `.whl` package directly [from here](https://www.wheelodex.org/projects/pmdarima/).

You need to download package corresponding to your python version and windows bits. E.g. if you have Python 3.7 and Windows 64-bit then download `pmdarima-1.7.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl` (or with `win32` suffix for 32-bit windows), here `cp37` means `CPython version 3.7`.

Then just install it like this:

```
pip install pmdarima-1.7.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

Also many trouble-some Windows prebuild `.whl` packages that have problems with installation/compilation are [located here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/). I've often downloaded this prebuilt packages from there, when haven't succeeded with pip install. But for the case of `pmdarima` it is located at the first link but not second.

Comment: @newinPython Just do command `pip install pmdarima` and then use like `import pmdarima`.

Comment: I'm getting same error `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pmdarima (from versions: )`
No matching distribution found for pmdarima`

Comment: @newinPython Updated my answer for the way of manually downloading/installing package directly.