# ModuleNotFoundError: Pyramid

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm trying to import these libraries:

```
from math import sqrt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error, mean_squared_error
from pyramid.arima import auto_arima
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
```

But this error is coming again and again
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyramid'**
I have tried `pip install pyramid-arima` but it's also throwing me so many errors in cmd.

Can anyone suggest to me what I can do to resolve this problem?

Comment: You don't mention anything about what version of things you're using.  "pyramid-arima" is very old and abandaoned, and probably doesn't support your Python.  The replacement is called pmdarima.  You should use that one instead.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64030188/how-to-install-pyramid-arima-in-python-3-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
pip install pmdarima
```

pmdarima is the official new name for pyramid.arima.

Comment: I have also added --user so that it can be installed properly in jupyter notebook. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install pmdarima by using pip:

```
pip install pmdarima
```

I also needed to modify my python script to use:

```
from pmdarima.arima import auto_arima
```